# core dump, <Address 0x5bf6 out of bounds>

Tags: c++

Getting core dump on very rare scenario. This code have been using from last 10 years and not faced this core till now and also no new code added to this. suspecting this is because of Addresses out of bounds and not sure to resolve this core. Asking some one's suggestion on this. Thanks in advance.

```
gdb) fr 8
#8  0x082905e0 in parse(_HTStream*, char const*, int) (me=0x83684f8, data=0x8368710 "", data_len=2896) at WMHttpStream.cpp:1497
1497    WMHttpStream.cpp: No such file or directory.
        in WMHttpStream.cpp
Current language:  auto; currently c++
(gdb) info locals
state = (parser_state *) 0x8368500
guid = {guid = "0&²u\216fÏ\021¦Ù\0ª\0bÎl", size = 2013}
data_cur = 0x83689bc "\202"
remaining = 2212
block_len = -135896812
type = -1
read_len = 684
parse_done = 1
block_buf = (data_buf_t *) 0x1
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "void parse(HTStream*, const char*, int)"
(gdb) fr 7
#7  0x0828d1c0 in process_file_data(_HTStream*, int, _buf_t*) (me=0x83684f8, type=0, block=0x833d4e0) at WMHttpStream.cpp:1062
1062    in WMHttpStream.cpp
(gdb) info locals
iov = {{iov_base = 0x8357de0, iov_len = 1250}, {iov_base = 0xffe87344, iov_len = 4293424288}, {iov_base = 0xffffffff, iov_len = 0}, {
    iov_base = 0xffffffff, iov_len = 4151443444}, {iov_base = 0xffe874a0, iov_len = 4293423940}, {iov_base = 0xffe873f0, iov_len = 4150651851}, {
    iov_base = 0xffe87344, iov_len = 4159359433}, {iov_base = 0xffe87420, iov_len = 4293424288}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 4222451713}, {
    iov_base = 0xffe874a0, iov_len = 4293424288}, {iov_base = 0xffe874a0, iov_len = 4293424288}, {iov_base = 0xffe874a3, iov_len = 4294967295}, {
    iov_base = 0xffe874a0, iov_len = 4294967295}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 0}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0x0,
    iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 742}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0xf44942f0,
    iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0x2, iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0x0, iov_len = 746}, {iov_base = 0x3fd18, iov_len = 4150704481}, {
    iov_base = 0xf7eae414, iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0xffe873d8, iov_len = 4150704481}, {iov_base = 0x835efe0, iov_len = 4293424288}, {
    iov_base = 0x2, iov_len = 22284}, {iov_base = 0x836850c, iov_len = 137132324}, {iov_base = 0xffe87418, iov_len = 136869189}, {
    iov_base = 0x8358016, iov_len = 137791248}, {iov_base = 0x2ac, iov_len = 136921305}, {iov_base = 0x82c7924, iov_len = 324}, {
    iov_base = 0x2630, iov_len = 136868550}}
n = 1
stime = 0
ptime = 3303
ds_type = 0
rc = 0
client = (WMHttpClient *) 0x8332688
state = (parser_state *) 0x8368500
stream = (stream_info *) 0x83326b8
asf_head = 0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>
len = 137790720
(gdb)
```

Here is sample code snippet:

```
void
process_file_data(HTStream *me, int type, data_buf_t *block)
{
    WMHttpClient *client = me->client;
    parser_state *state = &me->state;
    stream_info *stream = &client->_stream_info;
    char *asf_head;
    int len = 0;

    switch (type) {
    case BLOCK_HEAD:
    {
        len = state->block_len;
        asf_head = (char *)malloc(len);
        if (asf_head == NULL) {
            ad_debug_error("malloc(%d)", len);
            client->EventLoopStop(STOP_FOR_ERROR);
            break;
        }
        copy_from_buf(asf_head, block, len);
```

Comment: Do you have the actual code to share with us?

Comment: Are you sure this is the section of code causing the problem? And do you know if the calling procedure passed in a good `block` argument?

Comment: This snippet isn't enough.  Have you verified that `me` and `block` are actually allocated?  What about the members `client` and `state` and `_stream_info`?  You can add some debug statements, or use the debugger to find the values of `len` to make sure it is valid.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question.

Comment: There's no hint at what `iov` is but most of the values are suspiciously close to -1 when viewed as a signed int. I suspect the cause of the problem happens far from the point where you crash, or something is corrupting the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Is block allocated with sufficient buffer size? If not, please do so, Check with all such pointers, whether pointing to an allocated space before accessing